# How do I improve the below algorithm to recursively remove adjacent duplicate characters from right to left in a string?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

The problem statement is to remove duplicates in a string recursively. 
For eg: abcddaacg -> abccg-> abg

Now the algorithm I implemented is thus:

Keep 2 pointers (i and j). i is always < j. str[j] is always the element str[i] compares to remove duplicates. Hence when j = 6 and i = 5, I replace both of them with '\0' and then I update j to 7 (c). Then when j = 4 and i = 3 (both are d, j got updated cause str[4] != str[6] and hence j = i, became j = 4) we update both of them to '\0'.

My problem is with the next step when I update j to 7. For this I have to search for the next character which is not '\0'. This, is what is making it a O(n^2) implementation. How can I make this better ? O(n)

Below is the code:

```
static void remDups (String input) {

    char [] str = input.toCharArray();
    int j = input.length()-1;

    int i = input.length()-2;

    while (i >= 0){

        if (str[i] == str[j]) {
            str[i] = '\0';
            str[j] = '\0';
            j++;
            while (str[j] == '\0' && j < str.length) {
                j++;
            }
        } else {
            j = i;
        }
        i--;
    }

    i = 0;
    while (i < input.length()) {
        if (str[i] != '\0')
            System.out.print(str[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: First figure out a linear-time solution with an external stack. Then make it in place.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the expected result from `abbccbd`? Is it different from `abccbbd`? If you did this scan left-to-right naively, in the first case, you remove `bb` before `cc` so that the next `b` is in the output, but in the second case removing `cc` exposes `bbb` so the output is only `ad`. But, is this the expected result? Or to put it another way, is the order of removal well-defined?

Comment: Yes. Good point. The order of removal is right to left. so abbccbd should remove all three bs giving (ad)

Comment: There is no recursive call in your program

Comment: With the word recursive, I meant not just one naive pass.

Comment: @shrinidhisondur that's not what recursive means.

Comment: I used recursive for the reader to be clear that it's not simply removing characters that are next to each other.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann you can implement some recursive algorithms (including this one) with non-recursive method calls.  It requires far more state tracking, but it doesn't make the definition of how removals are to be done non-recursive.

Comment: I don't think that your current algorithm would handle @rici's `abbccbd` and `abccbbd` cases, because you're nulling out those characters and can no longer match the third b.  Can you confirm that you actually have to handle groupings of an odd number of letters, rather than just pairs?  (Even-numbered groupings are just multiple pairs in a row, so they fall under the category of "pairs".)

Comment: @shrinidhisondur: I would never have guessed from your question that you intended right-to-left removal (in fact, I was torn between left-to-right and simultaneous), so I think if you really care about the answer, you should edit the question to make that specification clear.

Answer (score 0):

The inefficiency in your algorithm comes from the fact that you're using a data structure (and an approach) that leaves empty space where removed pairs used to be, which makes it expensive to work around them.  I can think of a more efficient algorithm that uses your approach but a better data structure, and I can also think of a more efficient algorithm that uses a different approach.

This feels like homework, so I'd rather nudge you towards finding the answers on your own than give them to you directly, but I'd encourage you to figure out both algorithms I mentioned (different data structure but same algorithm, and different algorithm).  If you need a hint on either, reply in the comments and I'll work with you to get there...

EDIT: I just saw your comment saying that matching is right-to-left, so my alternate algorithm won't work.  But I'd encourage you to try to figure out what it would be, if greedy left-to-right matches were allowed.

EDIT 2: This algorithm actually will work with right-to-left matching, you just need to iterate right-to-left across the string.

Comment: Could you help me nudge in the right direction for the left to right algorithm ? I'd like to know that too.

Comment: My guess would be to store all the indices in a HashTable with values pointing to the next character that is not removed. So I won't have to search for the character each time. This will entail a space complexity of O(n) though.

Comment: What if instead of removing things from the full string, you instead built it one character at a time?  What options would that open up for you?

Comment: So I would have to add a character and then I may have to remove it from the string buffer right?

Comment: There you go.  All the additions and removals will be at the end (where it's O(1) each, with a max of N of each of them), so your algorithm would be O(N).

Comment: And I realized in the intervening time that you actually can apply that to a right-to-left removal; you just need to run the algorithm starting from the **end** of the string and working towards the **beginning**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative solution using a `stack` and removing adjacent duplicates on a `char[]` because they are easier to work with since `String` object is immutable.

On each iteration:

- use a boolean flag to keep track if any adjacent dups need to be removed.
- push elements that don't have equal adjacents onto the stack.
- if we found equal adjacents, increment counter while they are equal (as you may have more than two equal adjacent's) update the flag to say that adjacents dups need to be removed
- Otherwise we are done
- if the flag was activated, we overwrite our `char[]` with the non-dups that were stored in the stack and repeat the loop until no dups are removed.

Here is the code:

```
static char[] removeAdjDups(char[] data) {
    if (data == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
    boolean removal = true; // flag keeping track if any dups were removed
    char[] temp;
    while (removal) {
        /* set removal to false */
        removal = false;

        /* push elements that don't have equal adjacents onto the stack */
        for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i - 1] != data[i]) {
                stack.push(data[i - 1]);
            } else {
                while (i < data.length && data[i - 1] == data[i]) {
                        i++;
                }
                /* if we found equal adjacents, activate the removal flag */
                removal = true;
            }

            if (i == data.length - 1) {
                stack.push(data[i]);
            }
        }

        /* if dups were removed
           store the array with removed adjacent dups into original data */
        if (removal) {
            temp = new char[stack.size()];
            for (int i = temp.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                temp[i] = stack.pop();
            }
            data = temp;
        }
    }

    return data;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "abcddaacg";
    System.out.println(removeAdjDups(str.toCharArray()));
}
```

Output:

```
abg
```

Comment: Does it work with @rici's `abbccbd` and `abccbbd` samples, with odd-numbered groupings?  I suspect it won't, though I might be wrong.

Comment: well, right now it removes all adjacent duplicates, scan by scan, so it would give the same answer `abd` for these two strings instead of giving `ad` for `abccbbd` like @rici's said. This can be changed easily though by just breaking out of the inner loop as soon `removal` becomes true. It will also slow down the algorithm as this means only one pair can be removed during a scan...

Comment: You're right that breaking out of the loop would handle trios as well as pairs, though as you pointed out, your performance in the worst-case scenario (`abcdefghiihgfedcba` => empty string) would be O(N^2), which wouldn't meet the OP's requirement for something more efficient than the code posted.  Also, to meet his right-to-left removal requirement, you'd need to start from `data.length - 1` and work down to `0`, rather than the other direction.

Comment: @Tim yes you are absolutely correct, my point was to give an **alternate** solution using a stack that he might find useful, that was all.
I didn't say it was an improvement :)